# Struts 2 Validation - Do expression & fieldexpression validators support automatically rendering client-side for OGNL expressions?

Tags: javascript, validation, struts2, client-side

Do the Struts 2 `expression` and/or `fieldexpression` validators support automatically rendering client-side ECMAScript/JavaScript validation for the OGNL expression defined in the validation XML file, like what is done for the other [bundled validators](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/validation.html#Validation-BundledValidators) (`requiredstring`, `stringlength`, etc.)?

I ask, because the following ECMAScript is rendered for client-side for this form, and I don't see my OGNL expression anywhere.  I've tried the `expression` and `fieldexpression` validators and they both render this:

```
function validateForm_dlgIdSearch_form() {
    form = document.getElementById("dlgIdSearch_form");
    clearErrorMessages(form);
    clearErrorLabels(form);

    var errors = false;
    var continueValidation = true;
    // field name: searchFilter.number
    // validator name: fieldexpression
    if (form.elements['searchFilter.number']) {
        field = form.elements['searchFilter.number'];
        var error = "Employee number is required.";
    }

    return !errors;
}
```

I am trying to require at least one of three search fields, and I'm not sure if I've made a mistake or if Struts 2's validation doesn't support automatic client-side ECMAScript generation for `expression` and `fieldexpression` validators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing, I'm convinced that `expression` and `fieldexpression` validators do not render client-side JavaScript validation.